# Turkish character to english characters change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input. When i write text to first one,second one automatically  is written,

```
  $('#menutitle').keyup(updateCount);
            $('#menutitle').keydown(updateCount);

            function updateCount() {
                var cs = $(this).val();
                $('#menuseo').val(cs.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase());
            }
```

When I write Kullanıcı Grupları to first input, second input will be written as kullanici_gruplari, but it is written kullanıcı_grupları.

I need to change ş>s , ı>i , ö>o , ü>u , ğ>g , ç>c .How can i do it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```js
$(function() {

  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    var charMap = {
      Ç: 'C',
      Ö: 'O',
      Ş: 'S',
      İ: 'I',
      I: 'i',
      Ü: 'U',
      Ğ: 'G',
      ç: 'c',
      ö: 'o',
      ş: 's',
      ı: 'i',
      ü: 'u',
      ğ: 'g'
    };

    var str = $('#input').val();

    str_array = str.split('');

    for (var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++) {
      str_array[i] = charMap[str_array[i]] || str_array[i];
    }

    str = str_array.join('');

    var clearStr = str.replace(/[çöşüğı]/gi, "");

    $('#text-english').html(clearStr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Enter your text</h3>

<input type="text" id="input">
<div>
  <span id="text-english"><span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Tr2En(text){
    var Maps = {
        "İ":"I","Ş":"S","Ç":"C","Ğ":"G","Ü":"U","Ö":"O",
        "ı":"i","ş":"s","ç":"c","ğ":"g","ü":"u","ö":"o"
    };
    Object.keys(Maps).forEach(function(Old){
        text    = text.replace(Old,Maps[Old]);
    });
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This doesn't work if the string has repeating characters; it only replaces the first occurrence. I'd do it like this:
`let newText = "";
[...text].forEach((char) => newText += (Maps[char] ? Maps[char] : char) );
return newText;`

Answer (score 0):

```
const TrToEn = (text) => {
        return text.replaceAll('Ğ','g')
            .replaceAll('Ü','u')
            .replaceAll('Ş','s')
            .replaceAll('I','i')
            .replaceAll('İ','i')
            .replaceAll('Ö','o')
            .replaceAll('Ç','c')
            .replaceAll('ğ','g')
            .replaceAll('ü','u')
            .replaceAll('ş','s')
            .replaceAll('ı','i')
            .replaceAll('ö','o')
            .replaceAll('ç','c');
    };
```